# Highest block size for dd command

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

I want to run `dd` over a SanDisk 32GB micro SD but I'm not sure how to decide on the block size.

Usually I use `bs=1M`, but could I go any higher than that?

Comment: Byte speed :) ? bs means [Block Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29#Block_size).

Comment: I usually use 4M and it works OK, the difference will be very small so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go higher, but it probably won't make any difference. If you go too high, things might actually slow down.

Different SSD devices have different performance profiles. There is no universal, ultimate, answer that's right for every SSD device that exists in this entire world.

The only way to get the right answer is to experiment with various block sizes, and benchmark the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Try it!

```
#!/bin/bash
bs=( 32k 64k 128k 256k 512k 1m 2m 4m )
ct=( 32768 16384 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 )
for (( x=0;x<${#bs[@]};x++ )); do
   echo Testing bs=${bs[x]},count=${ct[x]}
   dd if=/dev/zero bs=${bs[x]} count=${ct[x]} of=junk
done
```

**Output**

```
Testing bs=32k,count=32768
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 3.094462 secs (346988217 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=64k,count=16384
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 3.445761 secs (311612394 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=128k,count=8192
8192+0 records in
8192+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 2.937460 secs (365534116 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=256k,count=4096
4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 3.247829 secs (330602946 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=512k,count=2048
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 3.212303 secs (334259206 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=1m,count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 3.129765 secs (343074260 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=2m,count=512
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 2.908048 secs (369231132 bytes/sec)
Testing bs=4m,count=256
256+0 records in
256+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 2.996609 secs (358318964 bytes/sec)
```

Comment: I had to change the lower case 'm' in blocksize to upper-case, I also upper-cased the k's so as to ensure the block sizes are base 2. As for testing on SSD's and other flash media, adding `rm junk` as the last line in the for loop will affect the speed as it changes the disk write to a plain write, rather than a possible read-modify-write. On my Samsung 850 Evo the changes made a large difference in apparent throughput, and results between different runs were much more consistent.